# Where can I see log from pub/sub api error for specific method?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm installing a pipeline with Terraform on GCP. The pipeline is not working but I'm not seeing any errors being logged. However when looking at Cloud Pub/Sub API service details I can this that the error rate for the following method `google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.StreamingPull` is at 100%. How can I have access the detail of these errors?

Comment: You may refer to this similar SO post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495143/error-code-503-in-gcp-pubsub-v1-subscriber-streamingpull which also encountered a 100% error rate on `google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.StreamingPull`

Comment: That is normal, https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull_has_a_100_error_rate_this_is_to_be_expected
Not to mention I don't see the connection between terraform deployments and pub/sub APIs, since the former don't use the latter (except to turn it on etc, but that won't block your terraform deployment).